# Disable comboxboxitem by binding to data bool

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp

I have a `ComboBox` in a UWP project. I am binding the `DataSource` to a collection of `MyItem` class. My class looks like this:

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INPC
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }



    #endregion
    private string _ItemName;
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return _ItemName; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ItemName)
            {
                _ItemName = value;
                Notify("ItemName");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _ItemEnabled;
    public bool ItemEnabled
    {
        get { return _ItemEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ItemEnabled)
            {
                _ItemEnabled = value;
                Notify("ItemEnabled");
            }
        }
    }}
```

Now I want the `ComboBoxItem` to be enabled or disabled depending on my `ItemEnabled` property. I researched and tried adding a binding through the Style tag but the binding does not function in UWP.

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ItemEnabled}" />
      </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

How can I solve this?

**EDIT 1**: Binding code

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItemsCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">           
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate>      
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}" />  
    </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you show the binding  to a collection of `MyItem` class too?

Comment: You can not use bindings in a style.

Comment: @Ken, ah right, so is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: Hi user 2946329, so the thing is, in the end my combobox will be part of an ItemsControl and therefore dynamically generated. So it will be difficult to explicitly set the itemssource for the ComboBox without overriding the generating of all the items. I'm really looking for something using XAML only or using a loop of some kind.... I tried setting every item explicitly upon the loaded event but the itemcontainer always results to null for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line (`ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItemsCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`) in XAML and add this line after `InitializeComponent();` in the code behind:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb1">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ItemEnabled}" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

And in `xaml.cs`:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cmb1.ItemsSource = MyItemsCollection;
}
```

***Edit:*** Another way is like this:

```
public Window1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext = MyItemsCollection;
}
```

And in the xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  ....
```

Comment: Does not work for me, I am seeing the @Ken 'can't use bindings in Setters' effect. True or false in the style will enabled disable all items, but a binding is ignored